# Ethereum generating genesis Python Syntax

Tags: python, ethereum

Hi I tried to generate the genesis file but get this error:

```
C:\Python34>python mk_genesis_block.py --extradata 0x11bbe8db4e347b4e8c937c1c837
0e4b5ed33adb3db69cbdb7a38e1e50b1b82fa > genesis_block.json
  File "mk_genesis_block.py", line 293
    print json.dumps(evaluate(), indent=4)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Edit:
Here is the surrounding lines:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print json.dumps(evaluate(), indent=4)
```

Then it's EOF. The whole file can be viewed [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ethereum/genesis_block_generator/master/mk_genesis_block.py)
Since the offending line seems to be only output, I commented it and got another error:

```
C:\Python34>python -tt mk_genesis_block.py --extradata 0x11bbe8db4e347b4e8c937c1
c8370e4b5ed33adb3db69cbdb7a38e1e50b1b82fa > genesis_block.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mk_genesis_block.py", line 124, in <module>
    EXTRADATA = (d[2:] if d[:2] == '0x' else d).decode('hex')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

which in conjunction with the other error makes me wonder whether a string instead of a json object is being operated on? Here is the whole arg parsing part:

```
# Grab the extra data command line argument
if '--extradata' in sys.argv:
    d = (sys.argv+[None])[sys.argv.index('--extradata') + 1]
    EXTRADATA = (d[2:] if d[:2] == '0x' else d).decode('hex')
else:
    EXTRADATA = ''
```

I also made a test file importing the json package, dumps and decode methods work.

Comment: try `python -tt mk_genesis_block.py --extradata  x11bbe8db4e347b4e8c937c1c837` this is usually an indentation problem

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is still there (identical output). I also checked the file, there's only spaces and LF's, and indentation seems ok.

Comment: without seeing at least the line before (and maybe more) I doubt anyone can help you ... the line indicated is certainly not a syntax error ...

Comment: I tried it on another freshly installed Win 8 machine where I also installed  python but still get the same error. Could it be be the python version (3.4.3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` in python3 is a method not a statement `print( "text" )` ... also I believe `str.decode` was remove in python3 ... instead use `codecs.decode(my_str,encoding)`

Comment: Oh I remember now... everything is coming back. Python 3 is not downward compatible to 2. I won't forget again.